# How to break trigger event?

Tags: oracle

There is some trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER `before_insert_trigger` BEFORE INSERT 

ON `my_table` FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE `condition` INTEGER:=0;

BEGIN

    IF **** THEN
        condition=1;
    END IF;

    IF condition <> 0 THEN    
        --Here I need to break trigger or event or smth to prevent
        --INSERT to be done    
    END IF;

END;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To prevent the statement from succeeding, simply raise an error. This will rollback the **statement** (each statement is atomic, it fails or succeeds entirely). You won't lose work done in this transaction before the beginning of the insert.

You could use the `raise_application_error` procedure to raise the error.

Here is a small example:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE foo (ID NUMBER);

Table created

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg BEFORE INSERT ON foo FOR EACH ROW
  2  BEGIN
  3     IF :new.id = 2 THEN
  4        raise_application_error(-20001, 'Id should not be "2"');
  5     END IF;
  6  END;
  7  /

Trigger created

SQL> INSERT INTO foo (SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 2 FROM dual);

INSERT INTO foo (SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 2 FROM dual)

ORA-20001: Id should not be "2"
ORA-06512: at "VNZ.TRG", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'VNZ.TRG'

SQL> select * from foo;

        ID
----------
```

Answer (score 5):

I would try to do whatever I could to embed this logic in a check condition rather than a trigger.

Comment: Yes, unless he wants the behaviour to be "all or nothing".

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, Jeffrey. Can you expand on that?